# What path should a file have to be found from web project?

Tags: java, servlets

I really don't understand from what "point" files are looked for.
I have conventional project. It has a class (placed in src\chat) that gets properties from config.properties and writes/reads xml file. Both of them are placed in src\resources. This project works fine. Properties are got by ResourceBundle.

[image: Conventional project]

When I copy this packages to dynamic web project and call methods of the class from servlet than the class can find properties and can't find xml file.

[image: Web project]

I found a lot of question like mine. But the solution was to use getServletContext().getResourceAsStream or getServletContext().getRealPath. But my class is not servlet.

The question is if it's possible to place the file anywhere and just write relative path to property? (For example in WebContent\xml)

Answer (score 0):

If your file is on classpath (and from those images it looks like it should be) then you can use something like this:

```
ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/file.txt");
```